# Defining an Inner class member function template with a (non type) enum argument

Tags: c++, templates, inner-classes, specialization, non-type

I'm having difficulty defining and specializing a member function `update()` of an inner class `Outer<T1>::Inner` that is templated on a non-type (enum) argument.

```
#include <cstdlib>

template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        enum Type{ A , B , C };

        template<Type T2>
        void update();
    };
};

// Definition
template<typename T1>
template<Outer<T1>::Inner::Type T2>
void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()
{
}

// Specialization
template<typename T1>
template<Outer<T1>::Inner::A >
void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()
{
}

int main()
{
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I'm getting the following error message in GCC 4.5.3

```
prog.cpp:17:28: error: ‘Outer::Inner::Type’ is not a type
prog.cpp:18:6: error: prototype for ‘void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()’ does not match any in class ‘Outer<T1>::Inner’
prog.cpp:11:15: error: candidate is: template<class T1> template<Outer<T1>::Inner::Type T2> void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()
prog.cpp:24:28: error: ‘Outer::Inner::A’ is not a type
prog.cpp:25:6: error: prototype for ‘void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()’ does not match any in class ‘Outer<T1>::Inner’
prog.cpp:11:15: error: candidate is: template<class T1> template<Outer<T1>::Inner::Type T2> void Outer<T1>::Inner::update()
```

---

BTW, unlike GCC, Visual Studio 2008 is unable to compile the following

```
template<typename T1>
struct Outer
{
    struct Inner
    {
        enum Type{ A , B , C };

        template<Type T2>
        struct Deep;
    };
};

template<typename T1>
template<typename Outer<T1>::Inner::Type T2>
struct Outer<T1>::Inner::Deep
{
};
```

Comment: I have to admit this genereated one of the more humorous error messages from VC2012 I've seen in awhile: `error C2244: 'Outer<T1>::Inner::update' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration, definition 'void Outer<T1>::Inner::update(void)', existing declarations :'void Outer<T1>::Inner::update(void)'` The striking difference between the existing and desired declarations is so obvious, isn't it =P

Comment: I was about to remark that Visual Studio 2008 does not approve. Is there a workaround? I'm actually coding in VS. I use GCC for sanity compliance checks.

Comment: @Olumide will a runtime check suffice for what you're doing? The compiler will most likely optimise the check and dead code away since it knows it will always be true or false.

Comment: @SethCarnegie it would. However there'll be more than a few if-statements and I was looking to cut down on the number. Fortunately VS is able to compile `struct Deep<T2>` if the enum is not in class scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you're missing a `typename` before `Outer<T1>::Inner::Type`. You have to have it, even in a `template` type list, because `Type` is a dependent type.

Secondly, your specialisation syntax is wrong (the type goes in `<>` after the function name before the parentheses, not in the `template<>`), but even if it was correct, it would not be legal. You have to specialise the outer template `Outer` before you can fully specialise `update`, according to an unfortunate rule regarding explicit template specialisation.

Comment: For the benefit of the unenlightened: What would "specializing the outer template" look like in this case?

Comment: @us2012 it would just be `template<> template<> void Outer<int>::Inner::update<Outer<int>::Inner::A>()` or whatever. The point is that `Outer` has to be specialised as well.

Comment: @Seth Interesting. So there is no way to actually get the functionality that the OP intended, short of specializing for every possible type that might be used as a template parameter to `Outer`?

Comment: @us2012 unfortunately yes, that is correct. I was surprised too, but §14.7.3/16 says _In an explicit specialization declaration for a member of a class template or a member template that appears
in namespace scope, the member template and some of its enclosing class templates may remain unspecialized, except that **the declaration shall not explicitly specialize a class member template if its enclosing class templates are not explicitly specialized as well**._ I think they just wanted to reduce a level of complexity for compiler writers.

Comment: FYI Clang is at fairly clear on their error message for this if you try to do it without specializing `Outer<>` : "Cannot specialize (with 'template<>') a member of an unspecialized template", which is a helluva lot more informative than Herb's messaging from VC++ (see comment in question).