# VS error referencing class-local typedef as non-inline template argument

Tags: c++, visual-studio, templates

The following bit of [code](http://ideone.com/LmQ3tM) (a MWE) compiles in gcc 4.5.3 and above but does not compile in VS 2008 and 2010. Is it a known VS compiler bug? And are there any workarounds, other than to define `func()` inline.

```
enum DeviceState{ ON , OFF , BUSY , WAITING };

template<typename T>
struct Foo
{
    typedef DeviceState State;

    template<State S>
    void func();     // no error if implementation is inline
};

template<typename T>
template<typename Foo<T>::State>
void Foo<T>::func()
{
}

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar> f;
    f.func<ON>();
}
```

VS error message

```
error C2244: 'Foo<T>::func' : unable to match function definition to an existing declaration
        definition
        'void Foo<T>::func(void)'
        existing declarations
        'void Foo<T>::func(void)'
```

Edit:
This appears to be another version of an [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14776699/defining-an-inner-class-member-function-template-with-a-non-type-enum-argument) issue I reported.

Comment: I don't know if it is a *known* compiler bug, but it seems it is a compiler bug. Your code is legal

Comment: I don't know whether it's a known bug but VS2012 also refuses to compile with C2244.